# Bukkit dispatchCommand not working

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am just starting out with java. I'm trying to simulate a command being triggered. I'm having troubles with the following:

```
log.log(Level.INFO, line); //outputs "say some text here"

Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), line);
Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "say hi");
Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "help");
```

they all say "Unknown command. Type "help" for help." in the server cmd window. any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? Send a message to all players, or to one specifically?

Comment: I'm trying to simulate a command (it reads out a configuration file, replaces for example {time} with the timestamp, and executes the command)

Comment: Humor me and try "/say hi" and "/help"

Comment: in the console? "say hi" and "help" (or "/say hi" and "/help" as a player) work fine, or do you mean in the code? in the code it doesn't work, I already tried that

Comment: Well, then I'm tapped for ideas. According to https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/send-and-execute-commands.81049/#post-1166298 you are doing it correctly. Sorry I couldn't be more help :(

Comment: Your code definitely should work. Near identical code to yours works fine in my plugins. As an added note, you can replace `Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand` with `Bukkit.dispatchCommand`. It won't fix your problem, but it's more concise and does the same thing.

Comment: Where is this in your code? If it's in your on-enable, try putting it somewhere else, or create a `SyncDelayedTask` for 10-20 seconds and then run the dispatch command code... It could be because Bukkit is not yet fully enabled

Answer (score 1):

I finally found what was causing it; it was being caused by me using a development snapshot version of craftbukkit rather then the recommended build.

Answer (score 0):

For doing this I usually use: `myPlugin.getServer().dispatchCommand(myPlugin.getServer().getConsoleSender(), "say hi");`
Hope this helps!